# How does iOS solve memory fragmentation?

Tags: ios4, memory-fragmentation

I couldn't find any documentation about memory management of iOS. Especially about memory fragmentation. If you know any document about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Memory fragmentation correction is an implementation detail.  You should never, in any way, directly deal with it.  However if you are worried that your objects will be moved around without notifying your code, don't; apple never moves objects - end of story.  Once memory is allocated, it's yours (even if a framework class's instance is occupying it) until it is deallocated.  That being said, from an academic perspective I see no reason why the iPhone shouldn't use at least a similar strategy to MacOS, on which there is an excellent article [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html).